# Angular - Update HTML when promise il resolved

Tags: angular, promise

I have a problem with Angular and Promises I don't understand.

This is my html:

```
<div>Is Ready? {{isReady}}</div>
<div *ngIf="isReady">Show this</div>
<div *ngIf="!isReady">Show that</div>
```

This is my TS file:

```
isReady: boolean = false;

constructor(
 private myService: MyService){
 await this.giveMeSlowData();
}

async giveMeSlowData() : Promise<void>{
 console.log(await this.myService.getResult());
 this.isReady = await this.myService.getResult();
}
```

Usually everything in this {{}} in HTML changes as soon as the variable in TS file.
But not now.
I can see console log after 5-6 seconds, but the HTML doesn't change. Why?

Thanks anyone!

Comment: The code looks like it should work.  Are you sure that `getResult()` is emitting a truthy value?

Comment: I don't think awaiting in the constructor is valid in TypeScript. FWIW, you may want to check the `async` pipe (and perhaps convert your promises into observables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this never completes  yet you get your console log.

### Actual problem

You have an `async` method that never returns anything. That leaves the `Promise` hanging forever. Since `await` is called on the hung `Promise` in the constructor, the component will never finish initializing. You can test this by adding a log statement in an `ngOnInit`.

### Recommendations

1. I would strong encourage you to switch to using an Observable as that is the standard practice in Angular world. A lot of things with component destruction is handled automatically for you that way. You can even do this without needing to change any logic of `MyService` which can be convenient if that must remain as a `Promise`-based class.
2. All initialization logic should be handled in an `ngOnInit` method, *not* in the constructor.
3. I would encourage you to switch to using the `async` pipe in the template on all of this.

### Solution

Here's how that all would come together.

`slow-data.component.ts`:

```js
isReady: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

constructor(
 private myService: MyService,
) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  giveMeSlowData();
}

giveMeSlowData(): void {
  from(this.myService.getResult()).subscribe(isReady);
}
```

`slow-data.component.html`

```
<div>Is Ready? {{isReady | async}}</div>
<div *ngIf="isReady | async">Show this</div>
<div *ngIf="!(isReady | async)">Show that</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whay are calling  this.myService.getResult() twice ?
try this :

```
async giveMeSlowData() : Promise<void>{
 this.isReady = await this.myService.getResult();
 console.log(this.isReady);
}
```